# MvvmCross binding in loop Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm stuck at a problem with MvvmCross.
I don't know how it's suppose to be handled.

The situation:

I have a object called

`MyTempClass`
It looks like this:

```
public class MyTempClass
{
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public bool IsTheCorrectAnswer { get; set; }
    public bool HasBeenClicked { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of `MyTempClass`.

From this list I iterate and create a view with buttons.

For each button I can successfully pass the object I'm iterating over in a command like this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < vmExercises.Count;  i++) //This is the list...
        {
            //Create btn & add to the view... 

            var currentExercise = vmExercises[i];
                            set.Bind(btn).WithClearBindingKey(currentExercise.ImageName).To(vm => vm.TestCommand).CommandParameter(currentExercise).Apply();
        }
```

The method that `TestCommand` uses looks like this:

```
    public IMvxCommand TestCommand => new MvxCommand<MyTempClass>(ATestMethod);

    private void ATestMethod(MyTempClass obj)
    {

        obj.HasBeenClicked = true;
        CurrentTempClass = obj;
    }
```

**The problem**

I also want to bind the visibility for the button in this loop. 
I've tried like this:

```
            set.Bind(btn).WithClearBindingKey(currentExercise.ImageName).For("Visible").To(vm => vm.ShouldBeVisible).Apply();
```

`ShouldBeVisible` looks like this:

```
    public bool ShouldBeVisible
    {
        get
        {
            if (CurrentTempClass.IsTheCorrectAnswer && CurrentTempClass.HasBeenClicked)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;

        }
    }
```

The problem is:

If one should be hidden, all of the other buttons gets hidden.

What am I doing wrong? Has anyone else done this?

I'm so thankful for any help! :)

Comment: for visibility, you should use the MvvmCross Visibility plugin: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/visibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for visibility, you should use the MvvmCross Visibility plugin: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/visibility

I would also recommend:
Removing logic form your getter and setters.
Call SetProperty() on theVisibility.Set for the Binding to work if the property gets updated.

Comment: Thanks @wishmaster
I solved it with the visibility plugin and conversion! :)

Comment: Happy to help @wallef